# Updating View after ng-model change - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I go about updating an array that is carrying my ng-model after a button click? I cannot bind them because the data I am selecting from is a list. For the data to update I have to change views or refresh but I would like it to update after I click the button

Here is my HTML and where I would like my ng-model text updated

```
'<span>HVACs: <ct-input  disabled="true"  ng-model="data.groupLimits[activeIndex].devices"  </ct-input> </span>' + '<br>' +
'<span> Add/Remove Device: <ct-input-list list="hvacsList"  ng-model="model"   </ct-input-list>' + '</span>' +
+ '<ct-button text="Add Device" show="true" ng-click="addDevice()"> </ct-button>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is loaded initially from a controller method call, just call that method at the end of whatever you are doing, eg

in controller:

```
$scope.LoadModel = function(){
    myService.loadModel(id).then(function(d){
        bindArrayToModel();
    })
}

$scope.DoClick=function(){
// something
 $scope.LoadModel();   // re-load model here
}
```

in view: